# Laravel 5.4 relationship

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I need to display users items from table name `Items`.

I have 3 models.

User model:

```
public function userItem()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserItem', 'item_id');
}
```

UserItem model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
}
```

What to write to `Item` Model to make this relationship successful. So I could display items from `items table`.

If I now do this:

I get info from `user_items` table from DB.

when I do this `@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)` I get this:

> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_items.user_items' in
>   'where clause'

Comment: So you have a users table, an items table and want to create something like an inventory, right?

Comment: Yes. I in my `user_items` table I get `user_id` and `item_id` @Astinox

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: How to display `items` from table `user_items` which collects this info: `user_id` and `item_id` ?

Comment: you said : I have 3 models. but you write 2 model in question what is the third model?

Comment: @Mohammadb `Item` model which is empty. I do not know what to write in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use many to many relation

you have 2 models User and Item

and 3 tables : -users -items -user_items

**User** Model should be like this:

```
public function userItem()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Item','user_items','user_id','item_id');
}
```

and **Item** Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','user_items','item_id','user_id');
}
```

and you need a table that you named it `user_items`

and you dont need to define userItem model you can remove relations in this model

in your blade use this code:

```
@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exhibiting a many-to-many relatioship, and yet using methods for one-to-many relationships. For a many to many relationship, use the following code in your models:

//user model:

```
public function userItem()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\UserItem', 'user_items', 'user_id', 'item_id');
}
```

//userItem Model:

```
public function user()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'user_items', 'item_id', 'user_id');
}
```

For a many-to-many relationship, you need a hasMany method on both your models.

For information on the parameters to the hasMany method as well as other information on many-to-many relationships, please read the documentation on many-to-many relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey when I do this `@foreach(Auth::user()->userItem as $item)` I get this: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_items.user_items' in 'where clause' `